# If statement, checking if one of two strings is on the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck on this simple if statement. If the string "AAA" is not on the sheet, but string "BBB" is. The code will not go to the ElseIf line of the code, but it will only throw an error.

> Run time error 91: object variable or with block not set

I have tried many different variations of the code, I will not post all of them as they all give me some sort of an error. :/

```
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("AAA") = "AAA" Then

        VarID= "AAA"
        MsgBox = VarID

    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("BBB") = "BBB" Then

        VarID= "BBB"
        MsgBox = VarID

    End If
```

Disregard the = sign next to MsgBox, MsgBox used just for simplification of the issue

Comment: No, the `.Find` method returns a range object. There is an example on the documentation page. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first check if there is a found range object.
Also your syntax for MsgBox is incorrect:

```
Dim R       As Range
Set R = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("AAA")

If Not R Is Nothing Then
    VarID = "AAA"
    MsgBox VarID
Else
    Set R = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("BBB")
    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        VarID = "BBB"
        MsgBox VarID
    End If
End If
```

Comment: yeah, just saw the MsgBox syntax, it was an accident, don't really care about it. I was trying to simplify the issue. Thank you

Comment: You should be able to  shrink this down to an inline query: `If Not(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("AAA") Is Nothing) Then`

Comment: @Chronocidal For teaching purposes, I chose to make minimal changes to the OP's code.  If your goal is short code (fewest keystrokes), the following is equivalent: `If Not [a1:bz999].Find("AAA") Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah, I made my comment because I thought that running the evaluation inline was less of a change to the code than adding an extra object and splitting each `If` into two lines.

Comment: @Chronocidal Just goes to show there are different approaches, and many different ways of solving a problem. In general, I prefer to work with defined objects; I find subsequent debugging easier, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two range variables:

```
Sub t()
Dim foundRange1 As Range, foundRange2 As Range
Dim varID As String
Set foundRange1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("AAA")
Set foundRange2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("BBB")
If Not foundRange1 Is Nothing Then ' If foundRange is *not* empty (Nothing), then it found the string.
    varID = "AAA"
    MsgBox varID
ElseIf Not foundRange2 Is Nothing Then
    varID = "BBB"
    MsgBox varID
End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you have a bunch of strings, you can use something like this loop:

```
Sub t2()
Dim strings() As Variant
Dim varID As String

strings = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")

Dim i As Long
i = 0

For i = LBound(strings) To UBound(strings)
    Do While Not ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find(strings(i)) Is Nothing
        varID = strings(i)
        MsgBox (varID)
        Exit For
    Loop
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
Sub qwerty()
If Not ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("AAA") Is Nothing Then

        VarID = "AAA"
        MsgBox VarID

    ElseIf Not ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("BBB") Is Nothing Then

        VarID = "BBB"
        MsgBox VarID

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to perform what other answers have expressed is the issue of the `.Find` function returning a range object:

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With mySheet

    Dim searchRng As Range
    Set searchRng = .Range("A1:BZ999")

End With

With searchRng

    If Not .Find("AAA") Is Nothing Then

        varID = "AAA"

    ElseIf Not .Find("BBB") Is Nothing Then

        varID = "BBB"

    End If

End With

MsgBox varID
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare `VarID` as `Variant` and remove the `=` in MsgBox:

```
Sub find()

Dim VarID As Variant

    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("AAA") = "AAA" Then

        VarID = "AAA"
        MsgBox VarID

    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BZ999").Find("BBB") = "BBB" Then

        VarID = "BBB"
        MsgBox VarID

    End If
End Sub
```